# How to add a shortcut keyboard in Eclipse to an action from a plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, salesforce, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using the Force.com plugin to facilitate coding Salesforce classes (java-like language).  When I right click in the text editor I get Force.com > Save to Server menu entry.

How do I assign a keyboard shortcut to this action?

Comment: Are you on a mac or a pc?

Comment: Does anything appear in Window > Preferences > General > Keys? If there is nothing there the menu item has not been set up to support a shortcut.

Comment: @greg-449 No, nothing.  I am wondering whether I can use something like AutoHotkey to map the shortcuts outside of Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to leverage Eclipe's macro plugin PracticallyMacro but it did not record right clicks.

Instead I came up with a solution using:

- '[TinyTask](http://www.vtaskstudio.com/support.php)' can export record and save as small 'exe' files which can then be added as external Eclipse builders
- '[TyperTask](http://www.vtaskstudio.com/support.php)' can automate tasks based on typed characters - epic.

[image: TinyTask as Macros for Eclipse]